# How can I query a remote Apache Tinkerpop Graph Database with Gremlin and Java?

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop

I haven't been able to find a comprehensive example of connecting to and then querying a remote Apache Tinkerpop Graph Database with Gremlin and Java. And I can't quite get it to work. Can anyone that's done something like this before offer any advice?

I've set up a Azure Cosmos database in Graph-DB mode, which is expecting Gremlin queries in order to modify and access its data. I have the database host name, port, username, and password, and I'm able to execute queries, but only if I pass in a big ugly query string. I would like to be able to leverage the org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph traversal methods, but I can't quite get it working.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Result;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

//More imports...

@Service
public class SearchService {
    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SearchService.class);

    @Autowired
    private GraphDbConnection graphDbConnection;

    @Autowired
    private Graph graph;

    public Object workingQuery() {
        try {
            String query = "g.V('1234').outE('related').inV().both().as('v').project('vertex').by(select('v')).by(bothE().fold())";
            log.info("Submitting this Gremlin query: {}", query);
            ResultSet results = graphDbConnection.executeQuery(query);
            CompletableFuture<List<Result>> completableFutureResults = results.all();
            List<Result> resultList = completableFutureResults.get();
            Result result = resultList.get(0);
            log.info("Query result: {}", result.toString());
            return result.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error fetching data.", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Object failingQuery() {
        return graph.traversal().V(1234).outE("related").inV()
            .both().as("v").project("vertex").by("v").bothE().fold()
            .next();
/* I get an Exception:
"org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteConnectionException: 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for an 
 available host - check the client configuration and connectivity to the 
 server if this message persists" */

    }

}
```

This is my configuration class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.MessageSerializer;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class GraphDbConfig {
    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GraphDbConfig.class);

    @Value("${item.graph.hostName}")
    private String hostName;
    @Value("${item.graph.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${item.graph.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${item.graph.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${item.graph.enableSsl}")
    private boolean enableSsl;

    @Bean
    public Graph graph() {
        Map<String, String> graphConfig = new HashMap<>();
        graphConfig.put("gremlin.graph",
                "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteGraph");
        graphConfig.put("gremlin.remoteGraph.remoteConnectionClass",
                "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection");
        Graph g = GraphFactory.open(graphConfig);
        g.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster()));
        return g;
    }

    @Bean
    public Cluster cluster() {
        Cluster cluster = null;
        try {
            MessageSerializer serializer = new GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0();

            Cluster.Builder clusterBuilder = Cluster.build().addContactPoint(hostName)
                    .serializer(serializer)
                    .port(port).enableSsl(enableSsl)
                    .credentials(username, password);
            cluster = clusterBuilder.create();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error in connecting to host address.", e);
        }
        return cluster;
    }

}
```

And I have to define this connection component currently in order to send queries to the database:

```
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class GraphDbConnection {
    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GraphDbConnection.class);

    @Autowired
    private Cluster cluster;

    public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) {
        Client client = connect();
        ResultSet results = client.submit(query);
        closeConnection(client);
        return results;
    }

    private Client connect() {
        Client client = null;
        try {
            client = cluster.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error in connecting to host address.", e);
        }
        return client;
    }

    private void closeConnection(Client client) {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot leverage the remote API with CosmosDB yet. It does not support Gremlin Bytecode yet.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/439

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/33632779-support-gremlin-bytecode-to-enable-the-fluent-api

You would have to continue with strings until then, though.....since you are using Java you could try a somewhat unadvertised feature: `GroovyTranslator`

```
gremlin> g = EmptyGraph.instance().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[emptygraph[empty], standard]
gremlin> translator = GroovyTranslator.of('g')
==>translator[g:gremlin-groovy]
gremlin> translator.translate(g.V().out('knows').has('person','name','marko').asAdmin().getBytecode())
==>g.V().out("knows").has("person","name","marko")
```

As you can see, it takes Gremlin `Bytecode` and converts it into a `String` of Gremlin that you could submit to CosmosDB. Later, when CosmosDB supports Bytecode, you could drop the `GroovyTranslator` and change from `EmptyGraph` construction of your `GraphTraversalSource` and everything should start working. To make this really seamless, you could go the extra step and write a `TraversalStrategy` that would do something similar to TinkerPop's `RemoteStrategy`. Instead of submitting `Bytecode` as that strategy does, you would just just use `GroovyTranslator` and submit the string of Gremlin. That approach would make it even easier to switch over when CosmosDB supports `Bytecode` because then all you would have to do is remove your custom `TraversalStrategy` and reconfigure your remote `GraphTraversalSource` in the standard way.

Comment: Thank you so much! The GroovyTranslator works just fine for me for now.